# Error: main method not found in class please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have written simple java code in notepad and trying to execute in command prompt.Getting

Error: Main method not found in class Box, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

```
class Box
{
int length,breadth,height;
public void setDimension(int l,int b,int h)
{
 length=l;
 breadth=b;
 height=h;
  }
 public void showDimension()
 {
System.out.println("l=" + length);
System.out.println("b=" + breadth);
 System.out.println("h=" + height);
  } }

 class example
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   Box smallBox= new Box();
   smallBox.setDimension(21,12,1);
   smallBox.showDimension();
}
}
```

Comment: What is your command prompt command?

Comment: Your code is working fine. Have you compiled your both classes? I have run it through eclipse and its working.

Comment: in compilation there is noerror while executing getting error.

Comment: @ sushobh command i have used javac Box.java then for executing java Box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you are executing it.

I have saved the above code as example.java in my machine and used the following commands in command prompt

For Compiling: javac example.java

For Executing: java example

Note that the main method is in example class so you have run the example class not the Box class

Edit:
Technically any java code can be compiled but for running a standalone application, the main method is needed. Even when you save the file as Box.java and compile it, there will be no compilation errors. But for running JVM needs main method. so you have to run example class not the box class

Comment: save it with Box and compile it  with Box.java no error will be there but while executing getting error

Comment: Though you saved the code as Box.java and compiled it, you have to execute example class since the main method is in it. JVM needs main method to start execution

Answer (score 2):

1. Make the example class as public
2. Give file name as example.java
3. Compile example.java and run

Answer (score 1):

Though you can save the file with Box.java. but when you compile the class, 2 .class files would be created.

1. Box.class
2. Example.class

you need you execute command "java example" on your command prompt.

Though best practices says:

1. Always make the class having main method as public.
2. Always save the fileName with public class name. (This is mandatory)
3. Always start class name with Capital letter.